# Is it secure to use HMAC to pass a string to be verified?

Tags: python, hmac

I am working on a Django project and trying to create a REST API to verify email without using any database. My present server connection is HTTP and not HTTPS.

So someone using the API end point POST his email:

```
REQUEST:

curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/openlogin' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"email":"test13@test.com",
}'
```

Now I am generating a random 6 digit number, eg. `435667`, and an email will be sent to `test13@test.com`:

```
send_mail('PIN TO VERIFY','ENTER THE PIN 435667',None,[test13@test.com])
```

The HMAC value of `435667` is sent as a response to the API call:

```
    raw = '435667'.encode("utf-8")
    key = 'SOME_SECRET_KEY'.encode('utf-8')
    hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, hashlib.sha1)
    pin_hmac_hash = base64.encodebytes(hashed.digest()).decode('utf-8')
    eg: pin_hmac_hash = "SOME_HMAC_HASH_OF_PIN"
```

So the response for `/api/openlogin` will be:

```
{
'email': 'test13@test.com'
'pin': "SOME_HMAC_HASH_OF_PIN"
}
```

Now the user sends me back the PIN along with the HMAC hash in the response:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/verifypin' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
'pin': "SOME_HMAC_HASH_OF_PIN",
'email': 'test13@test.com',
'emailed_pin':'435667'
}'
```

Could someone guess the PIN from `SOME_HMAC_HASH_OF_PIN`?

Of course I will further try to autenticate the API using JWT token. So the email cannot be tampered.

This is an example of PIN but it can be any string of sensitive information. Can I rely on HMAC?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are wanting to implement is a signed URL, similar to Amazon S3 URLs. As long as your secret is strong and secure it sounds like a reasonable way to verify the email address in a stateless fashion.

At the moment you are only signing/hasing the PIN and this is an issue with your code. If I get a valid PIN/PIN_HASH combination for email address A from your service, I could still submit this valid combination with a new email address B and it would pass your verification test.

I would suggest a slightly different solution. Use a timestamp instead of the PIN and use it as an expirey date.

```
created_at = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
payload = email + "-" + created_at
hashed = hmac.new(key, payload, hashlib.sha1)
```

Then send the created time back to the server instead of the pin. This allows you, after you verified that the hmac signature is correct, to also check how old this request is and reject it if it is older than x minutes.

This still leaves you vulnerable to replay attacks within the time frame, which might be ok, if you check that the user does not exist yet and reject the api call if they do.

PS: without https you are still at risk that someone intercepts and steals this information before it hits your server. I would strongly suggest to use https ([LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates are free and easy to get)

Comment: As you know i am not storing the PIN In my database. The only way i can know the pin is when the user sends me back the hash. if I use `raw = 'PIN-email'.encode("utf-8")` for `hmac.new(secret,raw,digest)` will that help

Comment: It ties the pin to the email, so yes, it is a better way to do it. The PIN will still be valid forever, as you have no way of checken when you sent the email.

Comment: For that i am going to add a timestamp and check the time elapsed. So `raw = 'PIN-email-timestamp'.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: What do you need the PIN for?